# Visual Studio 2017 native unit testing - reference to project doesn't work

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm using the Visual Studio 2017 native unit testing framework to test a C++ exe project *Foo* with a test project *FooTest*. I followed [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/19/cpp-testing-in-visual-studio/) to set this up.

I added a reference to Foo to FooTest. I can include Foo's files in FooTest with `#include "..\Foo\Foo.h"`. However, it doesn't seem to automatically link with Foo's compiler output, so I get lots of "unresolved external symbol" linker errors for things which are declared in `Foo.h` but defined in `Foo.cpp`.

Do I manually have to add folders to the project's library folders and link to the compiled output of Foo? Neither the tutorial nor [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp) indicate anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've read the docs, but maybe this reference was not one of them?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx

It's a VS2015 doc. Would the "Deciding how to test your code" section provide any clues?

Comment: Ugh. It's ugly that this must be done manually for each obj file. How do the 2017 docs even work for anyone?